# Windows loses login data for connected network drives on every restart

Tags: windows, connection, network-shares

This is a just a minor problem but it get's annoying over time:

I have two network drives on windows, each one of them maps a different server (1 Linux and 1 Mac). Every time I boot Windows (both in Vista and Windows 7) the two connections are still there - but I have to re-authorize again, though I checked that the connection should be recovered automatically next time.

The login screen for the network connection not even remembers my last login name (and also not the password, even if I ticked the checkbox).

Does anyone know how I can make Windows remember this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute `net use \\computer\share password /user:user` on each start-up. Easiest way is to write those commands into batch file and put it in startup folder.

Comment: Thanks, this did work - though I solved it now just by adding a password to my windows account. Then the password gets saved (strange).